Content hugging priority for the NSTableColumn in the view-based NSTableView
I have a simple view-based NSTableView with two columns: Name and Value (each cell contains a NSTextField-s)

I want to use the the screen space as much as possible to be able to display the long names and values. So, I configured the Column Sizing = Sequential and each cell view with maximum Content Hugging Priority = 1000

So, my expectation was that when I will increase the window width, the last column will be increased first to show as much content as possible.
Then, when all the content of the last column is visible, the first column will start to increase.
But actually I see the different behavior: the last column keeps growing even when all its content is visible, and stops only when it reaches the Max Width, configured for the column. And only after that does the first column start to grow. Here the view hierarchy (see the real cell content shown with the blue box)

Is there is a way to achieve the desired resizing behavior with the autolayout?

NSTableView doesn't use the constraints or the width of the text in the columns. You'll have to code this behaviour yourself (but I don't know if it's possible).
